# what is the good function php to deal with ffmpeg and progress bar

Tags: php, ffmpeg, progress-bar, exec, popen

I ask about ffmpeg and progressbar

I used exec function with ffmpeg  and output the result to txt file

and using some of code I found here to

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="es">
<title>AudioXtractor</title>
<body>
<center>



    <?php 

    define('RAPIDLEECH', 'yes');
    define('CONFIG_DIR', 'configs/');
    require_once('configs/config.php');
    define ( 'TEMPLATE_DIR', 'templates/'.$options['template_used'].'/' );
    // Include other useful functions
    require_once('classes/other.php');
    error_reporting(0);

    login_check();

    include(TEMPLATE_DIR.'header.php');

    echo ('<br><br><br><b>AudioXtractor</b>, un complemento <br> que te permite extraer el audio de tus videos.<br><br><br>');

    putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.')); ?>

    <br />

    <FORM method="post"><center>
    <TABLE>
      <td>Movie:
    <select name="video">

    <?php
    $exts=array(".ac3", ".avi", ".f4v", ".flv", ".mkv", ".mov", ".mp4", ".mpg", ".mpeg", ".rmvb", ".srt", ".swf", ".wav", ".wmv");
    $ext="";
    function vidlist($dir) 
    {
    $results = array();
    $handler = opendir($dir);
    while ($file = readdir($handler)) 
    {
    if (strrchr($file,'.')!="")
    {
    $ext=strtolower(strrchr($file,'.'));
    }
    if ($file != '.' && $file != '..' && in_array($ext,$GLOBALS["exts"]))
    {
    $results[] = $file;
    }
    }
    closedir($handler);
    sort($results);
    return $results;
    }
    function Output($command) {
    $output = array($command);
    exec($command.' 2>&1', $output);
    return ($output);
    }
    $files = vidlist("./files/");
    foreach($files as $file)
    {
        echo '<option value="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</option>';
    }

    ?>


    </TABLE>

    <br/ >
    New MP3's name: 
    <input type="text" name="nvdo" value="nuevoaudio"> 
    <br/ >
    <br />
    <br />

    <td colspan=2><center><input type=submit style="font-size:16px; font-weight:bold; cursor:pointer;" name="analize" value=Extract /></td>
    <tr>

    </FORM>


    <?php
    if ($_POST['video']!="")

        $video = 'files/';
        $video=array();     
        $video[0] = $_POST['video'];

    if ($_POST['nvdo']!="")

        $nvdo = 'files/';
        $nvdo=array();      
        $nvdo[0] = $_POST['nvdo'];



    foreach ($video as $vdo)
    foreach ($nvdo as $nvd)

    if (isset($_POST["analize"])) {

        exec("ffmpeg -i files/$vdo -ab 192k files/$nvd.mp3 -y 2> files/$nvd.txt");

        $ext=strtolower(strrchr($vdo,'.'));

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////my code //////////////////////////////////////////

    $content = @file_get_contents("files/$nvd.txt");


        //get duration of source
        preg_match("/Duration: (.*?), start:/", $content, $matches);

        $rawDuration = $matches[1];

        //rawDuration is in 00:00:00.00 format. This converts it to seconds.
        $ar = array_reverse(explode(":", $rawDuration));
        $duration = floatval($ar[0]);
        if (!empty($ar[1])) $duration += intval($ar[1]) * 60;
        if (!empty($ar[2])) $duration += intval($ar[2]) * 60 * 60;

        //get the time in the file that is already encoded
        preg_match_all("/time=(.*?) bitrate/", $content, $matches);

        $rawTime = array_pop($matches);

        //this is needed if there is more than one match
        if (is_array($rawTime)){$rawTime = array_pop($rawTime);}

        //rawTime is in 00:00:00.00 format. This converts it to seconds.
        $ar = array_reverse(explode(":", $rawTime));
        $time = floatval($ar[0]);
        if (!empty($ar[1])) $time += intval($ar[1]) * 60;
        if (!empty($ar[2])) $time += intval($ar[2]) * 60 * 60;

        //calculate the progress
        $progress = round(($time/$duration) * 100);




        echo '<BR><BR>¡Su video fue convertido correctamente! <BR><BR>Link al archivo:';

        echo ' <a href="files/'.$nvd.'.mp3">'.$nvd.'.mp3</a><BR />' . "<br>";
        echo "Duration: " . $duration . "<br>";
        echo "Current Time: " . $time . "<br>";
        echo "Progress: " . $progress . "%" . "<br>";

    //////////////////////////////////////my coed //////////////////////////////////////////////
    }

    ?>
    <br><br><a href="index.php">Volver al RapidLeech</a>

    <br><br><br>Formatos Aceptados: <br><b>.ac3, .avi, .f4v, .flv, .mkv, .mov, .mp3,<br> .mp4, .mpg, .mpeg, .rmvb, .srt, .swf, .wav, .wmv</b>
    <br><br>
    </center></body></html>

    <?php



    ?>
```

so i ask some one he told me the exec stop php script and never give me

```
You can't get the progress directly if you are using exec, because the php script is stopped until ffmpeg closes. (Because exec returns the whole execution output)

You should use popen, for being able to get the output from the process in real time (without reading any file) for parse and show the progressbar

Here is a example for get the output: 

When you get the progress info from ffmpeg, you can use your code for parse it and show your progressbar
```

this is my popen script

```
<?php 

$handle = popen ("ffmpeg.exe -i files/fz.mp4 -ab 192k files/vdf.mp3 2>&1 ", 'r');
$handles = (string)$handle;
$line = "";

while (false !== ($char = fgetc($handle)))
{
  if ($char == "\r")
  {
    // You could now parse the $line for status information.
    echo "$line\n";
    $line = "";
  } else {
    $line .= $char;
  }
  ob_flush();
  flush();
}
pclose ($handle);


    //get duration of source
    preg_match("/Duration: (.*?), start:/", $handles, $matches);

    $rawDuration = $matches[1];

    //rawDuration is in 00:00:00.00 format. This converts it to seconds.
    $ar = array_reverse(explode(":", $rawDuration));
    $duration = floatval($ar[0]);
    if (!empty($ar[1])) $duration += intval($ar[1]) * 60;
    if (!empty($ar[2])) $duration += intval($ar[2]) * 60 * 60;

    //get the time in the file that is already encoded
    preg_match_all("/time=(.*?) bitrate/", $handles, $matches);

    $rawTime = array_pop($matches);

    //this is needed if there is more than one match
    if (is_array($rawTime)){$rawTime = array_pop($rawTime);}

    //rawTime is in 00:00:00.00 format. This converts it to seconds.
    $ar = array_reverse(explode(":", $rawTime));
    $time = floatval($ar[0]);
    if (!empty($ar[1])) $time += intval($ar[1]) * 60;
    if (!empty($ar[2])) $time += intval($ar[2]) * 60 * 60;

    //calculate the progress
    $progress = round(($time/$duration) * 100);




    echo '<BR><BR>¡Su video fue convertido correctamente! <BR><BR>Link al archivo:';


    echo "Duration: " . $duration . "<br>";
    echo "Current Time: " . $time . "<br>";
    echo "Progress: " . $progress . "%" . "<br>";

//////////////////////////////////////my coed //////////////////////////////////////////////

?>
```

so i dont under stand what is good for ffmpeg progressbAR

is exec or popen

so please give me hints for ffmpeg real time progressbar

what is good for progressbar

is html5 progress bar

or javascript progress bar

Comment: check out one of my projects (ffmpeg converter in php): https://github.com/jmalinens/wap4 I will try to remember and find relevant parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach was something like this

```
$sCmd = "ffmpeg -i infile.mp4 ... -report outfile.mp4 > /var/log/ffmpeg.log";
$proc = popen($sCmd." 2>&1", "r");
$read = fread($proc, 2096);
pclose($proc);
```

Here is little bit modified code from one of my older projects. I hope it will give You some inspiration:

```
<?php
//get so far encoded time
public function getEncodedTime(){

    $FFMPEGLog = file_get_contents('ffmpeg.log');
    $times     = explode('time=', $FFMPEGLog);
    $ctime     = count($times)-1;
    $timed     = explode(' bitrate=', $times[$ctime]);
    //print_r($timed);
    $nEncTime  = $timed[0];
    list($h, $m, $s) = explode(":", $nEncTime);
    $s = ceil($s); // 21.40 seconds => 22 seconds
    $nEncTime = hms2sec($h, $m, $s);

    return $nEncTime;

}

//covert H:i:s time to seconds
public function hms2sec ($h, $m, $s) {

    //list($h, $m, $s) = explode (":", $hms);
    $seconds = 0;
    $seconds += (intval((string)$h) * 3600);
    $seconds += (intval((string)$m) * 60);
    $seconds += (intval((string)$s));
    return $seconds;

}


//get total length of file
public function getTotalTime()
{
    $play_time_sec = 0;

    $lines = file('ffmpeg.log');
    foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
        if(strpos($line, 'Duration') !== false) {
            $line = explode("Duration: ", $line);
            $line = explode(",", $line[1]);
            $line = explode(":", $line[0]);

            $play_time_sec = 0;
            $play_time_sec += intval((string)$line[0]) * 60 * 60; // hour
            $play_time_sec += intval((string)$line[1]) * 60; // minute
            $play_time_sec += intval((string)round($line[2])); // second
            break;
        }
    }

    return $play_time_sec;
}


//get percents completed:
public function getPercentsComplete()
{

    $sFileContents = file_get_contents('ffmpeg.log');
    if(stripos($sFileContents, 'No more inputs to read from, finishing') !== false) {
        return 100;
    }

    $nTotalTime = getTotalTime();
    $nEncodedTime = getEncodedTime();

    if($nEncodedTime <= 0)
        return 0;

    if($nEncodedTime >= $nTotalTime)
        return 100;

    $nPercentsComplete = round(($nEncodedTime/$nTotalTime)*100);

    return $nPercentsComplete;
}
```